# Magento categories and attributes

Tags: magento, attributes, seo, e-commerce, categories

Hi this is sort of very basic magento database question. I am creating a webstore where I am putting products example t-shirts which can be male t-shirts and female t-shirt. but when I create categories I see lot of redundant categories. I am doing it like this;

mens fashion->clothing->tshirt->type->brand
mens fashion->clothingtshirt->type->brand

or

mens accessories->eyeware->sunglasses->sports
womans accessories->eyeware->sunglasses->sports

so many categories seems like a nightmare to manage and pretty redundant which I think is not a good SEO thing as well. Is there a more simple way i.e attributes, what will be its cons and pros and is it good for SEO and would it have breadcrums as well?

Please guide.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use categories if you would like to optimize for SEO purposes and have breadcrumbs. However if you have to much categories while have a small amount of products, your customer needs to click to much to see their desired product. 
If you use attributes (dropdown/multi) you will be able to have filters for your customer. Your urls will be a mess though. The value used in urls will be an integer and not some text.
Take a look at custom routes (you can set via backend) for catalog products, you can define your own urls route to specific endpoints.